# Is it possible to define a new random variable like those listed in scipy.stats?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) is a list of random variable, is it possible to define a new one?

Comment: What's wrong with old ones?

Comment: There is not the one that I need, i.e. hyperexponential

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to subclass `rv_generic` and implement at least `_pdf` .
The docstring of `rv_continuous` gives some guidance